# Angularjs ngOption with array

Tags: angularjs, html-select

I want to add an html select with options AM,PM with angularjs,
what i need is having the key and the value of the option be the same :

```
<option value="AM">AM</option>
<option value="PM">PM</option>
```

My html looks like this

```
<select ng-model="ampm" ng-options="k as v for (k , v) in ampms"></select>
```

and my controller looks like

```
  $scope.ampm = (new Date().getHours()) >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
  $scope.ampms ={"AM":"AM","PM":"PM"};
```

and every thing working fine.

My question is why i cant have the same thing when i used an array (i tried all the options in the ng-options)
as this

```
$scope.ampms =["AM","PM"];
```

what ever i do i always get this

```
<option value="0">AM</option>
<option value="1">PM</option>
```

What i want is using an array like above with the option has the key and the value the same.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is is a default behavior of ng-options in Angular.  If you do not specify a key name, angular will automatically choose to use the index rather than a key.  The code that does that can be seen on [line 405 in /src/ng/directives/select.js on Angular's Github repository](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/select.js#L405).

It can't even be forced by "value as value for (index, value) in values".

But as dnc253 just beat me to the punch with his answer (it showed up while I was typing)... you don't have to worry about it, Angular does it all for you automatically.

Answer (score 26):

With AngularJS, you don't need to worry about what the value of the option is. All the selects I've seen with `ng-options` have values of 0 through whatever. If you're just looking for a dropdown with the two options, it can be as simple as

```
<select ng-model="ampm" ng-options="currOption for currOption in ['AM', 'PM']"></select>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/EyBVN/1/

Comment: I tried the link you listed ,still have the same values as 0,1 not AM,PM

Comment: Now that you've accepted the answer, do you understand what we're saying in the answers? It doesn't matter what the value attribute is set to. Angular will update your model correctly for you based on the selected option.

Comment: It matters if the target of the form (server) expects a string value rather than an index.

Comment: @LachlanCotter Angular isn't really designed to do form submits that reload the whole page. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/16945970/1014979

Answer (score 2):

I did find a way to place specific data in the value of the options for a select.  You have to add an ng-repeat attribute to the option tag inside the select tag:

```
<select id="{{question.id}}" name="{{question.id}}" 
    class="{{question.inputclass}}" ng-required="question.required" 
    title="{{question.title}}">
  <option value=""></option>
  <optgroup ng-repeat="group in question.data" label="{{group.group}}">
    <option ng-repeat="item in group.data" value="{{item.value}}" 
        ng-selected="{{item.value == question.defaultValue}}">
          {{item.description}}
    </option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

As a bonus, I left the option group tags in place to serve as an example for everyone.

The `question.data` `JSON` is:

```
[
  {"group":"Canada","data":[{"value":"Ontario","description":"Toronto"},
                            {"value":"Quebec","description":"Quebec City"},
                            {"value":"Manitoba","description":"Winnipeg"}
                           ]
  },
  {"group":"Mexico","data":[{"value":"Jalisco","description":"Guadalajara"},
                            {"value":"Nayarit","description":"Tepic"}
                           ]
  },
  {"group":"United States of America","data":[
                            {"value":"Alabama","description":"Montgomery"},
                            {"value":"Georgia","description":"Atlanta"},
                            {"value":"Mississippi","description":"Jackson"},
                            {"value":"Louisiana","description":"Baton Rouge"},
                            {"value":"Texas","description":"Ausint"}
                           ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you! I still can't explain why ng-options wasn't working for me, but thanks to your post I built the option list with ng-repeat and it is functioning well!