# Angular select with ng-option sends index instead of value when posting form

Tags: post, angularjs, html-select

When I post a form with an Angular select, it sends the array index of the selected option, not its value. I need the string to be sent because the server doesn't know about these indices. How can I fix this?

From [jsfiddle.net/2SuZG](http://jsfiddle.net/2SuZG):

```
<form method="post" action="/my/post/endpoint">
    <select name="resource" ng-options="r for r in ['a', 'b']"
            ng-model="selectedResource"></select>
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

You can see from the console output in the fiddle that the posted form is sending `resource=0`, but I want `resource='a'`. *(Note: In my fiddle, I am serializing the form, but this is only to see what it would be posting. In my app I am actually posting to a real endpoint.)*

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13692921/angularjs-ngoption-with-array), but the answer there was "don't worry about the value". But in my case, I am posting a form so I am concerned with the value. I must be missing something very basic here. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you wanting to use jQuery to `serialize` the form?  You're using Angular... so your form should be represented very nicely in your `$scope` if you've done things correctly.

Comment: Serialize is just for demo purposes, I added an update to clarify.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't be serializing your form with jquery since you have all of the pertinent data in the $scope and that's what you'd want to serialize (some subset or some object that you'd be posting with $http or $resource).  If you are dead set with your approach, create a hidden input with the real name of the data element:  http://jsfiddle.net/2SuZG/1/

```
<select name="resourceTemp" ng-options="r for r in ['a', 'b']"
        ng-model="selectedResource"></select>
<input type="hidden" name="resource" value="{{selectedResource}}" >
```

I wouldn't recommend this but it is what you'll want to do.

Comment: +1 for the hack answer and the best practice as well (serializing was just for testing).

Comment: I had to use `ng-value="selectResource"` instead of `value={{selectedResource}}`

Answer (score 3):

ng-option works on array. if you want to use ng-option make array like this

```
r = [{ "value": 1, "text": "a" }, { "value": 2, "text": "v" }];  

<select ng-option="obj.value as obj.text for obj in r">
```

Or you can use ng-repeat in your case

```
<form method="post">
        <select name="resourceTemp" ng-model="selectedResource">
            <option ng-repeat="r in ['a','b']" value="{{r}}">{{r}}</option>
        </select>
        <input type="hidden" name="resource" value="{{selectedResource}}" >
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nHyET/

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is to not post forms.  If you want to `POST` data to an endpoint, use [$http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http) or [$resource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource).

Check out Mark Rajcok's comment on the docs: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:select

Answer (score 0):

If you need to solve this anyway, and use AngularJS good practices are not applicable 'cause rush or requires massive changes, try this (it's worked for me):

```
<select id="resourceTemp" ng-model="selectedResource">
   <option ng-repeat="r in ['a','b']" value="{{r}}">
      {{r}}
   </option>
</select>

<input type="hidden" name="resourceTemp" ng-value="selectedResource">
```