# Angular.js submit form old way

Tags: html, forms, angularjs

I'm migrating an old html page from jQuery to Angular, and it contains some old-school forms with `<input type="submit">`. When I enriched my pages with the `ng-app` directive, the old forms stopped working (I mean when you press the `submit` buttons then nothing happens).

I searched for this problem and scanned the Angular docs too, but it seems that nobody is submitting forms anymore.

Any suggestions on how to bring those forms to life again without much keystrokes would be appreciated.

Currently the form has following markup:

```
<form name="form_upload" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file">
<input type="submit" name="send" value="Upload">
</form>
```

All jQuery code I purged and starting fresh with Angular.

**UPD:**

I guess i now found cause, it's empty `action` attribute, it seems empty action is not welcomed by standarts, but very convenient to use allowing you to submit form to the current page URL, is there Angular way to do it ?

Comment: How does you use to submit your forms? Do you use jQuery for the work?

Comment: It should work, except for the action is empty. Look http://plnkr.co/edit/clDeu8NVLCXLh2vojjxp?p=preview

Comment: Yes, it's empty action, thanks for the hint

Comment: So it's working now or were you submitting it with jQuery?

Comment: Please check question update, i currently looking for correct way to submit to the same page, becaue hardcoding url in action atrribute is not desired option.

Comment: had this same issue, and adding action did solve.
The docs don't have action in the form tag:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit very strange

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Going off of the docs: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:form

Angular's philosophy is to minimize data and page reloads, so they don't like "old school forms", but you can get around it by using an `action` attribute in the form.

Angular is designed with single page applications in mind and avoiding full page reloads as that is going to take longer to do.  By using the `ngSubmit` directive, you can define a function to send over the form data to the server and get a response back much quicker than a full page reload.  Bytes instead of Kilobytes.

Comment: An answer would also have answered his question. I have been trying to figure out how to submit with an action attribute to the page you're on, when the url is hashed because it's a url for reseting your password, for example. What ended up working after pulling out some hair was `action="#"`

Comment: but sometimes you have to submit it the traditional way, e.g. facebook redirect. you have to reload the page. how can you do that?

Comment: Another exemple is integration with Symfony and Angular Material. You like the symfony way to handle everycase, and a neat interface

Comment: This seems like a pretty ugly hack, any idea why it is the way it is?

Answer (score 11):

- Use a non-empty `action` attribute to make Angular submit the form
- Fill `action` attribute with current location (using angular)

In your controller:

```
$scope.location = $window.location.href
```

In your HTML:

```
<form action="{{location}}">
```

See the [plunkr demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/qBTuc5VP1z1plxdSxt5J?p=preview).

Comment: This is a better answer to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this.  I'm pretty sure I was using jquery to submit the form, but you could probably do it with plain old javascript.

One of the comments on the angular form page suggests this:

```
<input onclick="javascript:$(this).parent().submit();" type="submit" value="">
```

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:form

Comment: in plain javascript: this.form.submit();

Comment: Since when did $(this) become plain old javascript??

Comment: @Red2678 Ouch.  :-)  In my defense, angular comes packaged with something they call jQuery lite, so if you're using angular, $(this) is valid javascript.