# Angular ng-options setting values to be same as in object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

I am trying to make the value attribute equal to the value of what it would look like in the object.

For example:

Object:

```
$scope.tagSelect = [
        { Name: 'Must have', Value: 1 },
        { Name: 'Must not have', Value: 2 }];
```

Angular HTML:

```
<select ng-options="select.Value as select.Name for select in tagSelect" ng-model="tag.MatchLogic"></select>
```

Output:

```
  <select ng-options="select.Value as select.Name for select in tagSelect" ng-model="tag.MatchLogic" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
        <option value="0" selected="selected">Must have</option>
        <option value="1">Must not have</option>
  </select>
```

That is not exactly what I want. What I want is for the option values to equal what is in my object.

More Like Below:

```
<option value="1" selected="selected">Must have</option>
<option value="2">Must not have</option>
```

Comment: That's actually necessary? Because you know, your model does have the right Value.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13692921/angularjs-ngoption-with-array/13693979

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your way is correct, the model value updates correctly but the HTML `value` attributes are not the same value. Weird behaviour, but it looks like it's wanted.

```
ng-options="select.Value as select.Name for select in tagSelect"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nicolasmoise/Y8C5A/

Notice how the ng-model is updated with correct value.

Comment: My tag.MatchLogic is set from the db in some instances. I is just stored as an id value example 1 or 2. When I bring it in it doesn't automatically select the corrent id. Instead it is blank in the select box.

Comment: So something like this http://jsfiddle.net/nicolasmoise/Y8C5A/1/? Works fine for me

Comment: Hmm I found it is deefiniety making the html option selected but just not selecting it. must be a style issue? will work on that.